# The union of a increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras is an algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that the union of a **strictly** increasing sequence of $\sigma$-algebras is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Further I know that the union of a increasing sequence (not strictly) of algebras is an algebra.

But what about the union of a increasing sequence (not strictly) of $\sigma$-algebras to be an algebra?

Comment: Every $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra, so this is true and it's a consequence of your second sentence.

Comment: What difference does it make whether it is strictly increasing or not?

Answer (score 2):

Any $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra, so....